# Write to a public folder in google drive using android API

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

How to write to a public folder created and maintained by a master account. All the clients(android-device) must be able to write to that public folder of google drive ?

Comment: Show the code you tried. Otherwise its too broad.

Comment: Can you also explain what you are trying to achieve? Without further deals, it sounds like you are heading towards pain with this model. We can potentially help avoid that pain by suggesting better models to achieve your goal.

Comment: @DanMcGrath  I m trying to create a collective photos app . the app will take pictures and write those pictures to a single google drive account . That google drive account will be owned and maintained by me

Comment: Drive (and integrations with it) are about user-owned content. What you describe appears to be for data not owned by the app user, so using a 'master' account in such a manner is not encouraged. You will run into quota limits for a single 'user' (or master/service account) if your app is successful that will cause issues so I encourage you to look for a different way.

Comment: @DanMcGrath sure i ll think about it

Comment: I had a similar idea about using one central folder, but @DanMcGrath, I think I see what you're saying about quota limits.  In my case, it's only a handful of users, though.  My question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44143307/accessing-public-google-drive-folder-from-android-app-without-authenticating